# Scrollview not scrolling in Android (AdjustPan)

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-scrollview

Here is a my scrollView xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/myCoordinator"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_toolbar"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/u_back_action"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/arrow_back_blue" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headerTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/u_my_page"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/my_profile_edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="8dp"

            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/u_save"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/user_header_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/u_user_fullname"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/u_common_text_size"

                    />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/personal_settings"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/u_personal_settings_txt"
                    android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#cccccc" />


                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_edittext_action"
                    android:textColor="#4d4d4d"

                    android:textColorHint="#b3b3b3">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/first_name_lat"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:hint="@string/u_first_name_lat"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"

                        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                        android:textColor="#4d4d4d"

                        android:textColorHint="#b3b3b3"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_edittext_action"
                    android:textColor="#4d4d4d"

                    android:textColorHint="#b3b3b3">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/last_name_lat"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:hint="@string/u_last_name_lat"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"

                        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                        android:textColor="#4d4d4d"

                        android:textColorHint="#b3b3b3"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_edittext_action"
                    android:textColor="#4d4d4d"

                    android:textColorHint="#b3b3b3">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/u_address"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:hint="@string/u_address"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"

                        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                        android:textColor="#4d4d4d"

                        android:textColorHint="#b3b3b3"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_edittext_action"
                    android:textColor="#4d4d4d"

                    android:textColorHint="#b3b3b3">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/u_gender"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:hint="@string/u_gender"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"

                        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                        android:textColor="#4d4d4d"

                        android:textColorHint="#b3b3b3"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

In my activity's SoftInputMode is adjustNothing.

As i said my scrollview not working.I search about my problem ,one solution is to change adjustResize,but i don't want this solution, because my AppBarLayout layout moving up.

My questions is that, is it a possible to move scrollview at the moment(adjustNothing).I can't show my last edittext when keyboard is showing.
Or,Is it a possible to disable move up AppBarLayout layout in my xml if I use adjustResize or adjustPan ?
Thanks everyone

Comment: I am facing same issue. Can you share how you got rid of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

Add this line in NestedScrollView 's child Layout

```
android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
```

and manifest file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```